# Android View InflateException: Binary XML File line #63 Error inflating class <unknow>

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-layout

i dont have errors project be like clean but doesnt work on test
wherever I looked this error but i couldnt find anyting
i dont have errors project be like clean but doesnt work on test
wherever I looked this error but i couldnt find anyting

ERRRORS
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qdlwpluf3m5w20n/FjJxZxBJEE

```
   package com.martlost.esrarengizolaylar;





import com.searchboxsdk.android.StartAppSearch;
import com.startapp.android.publish.StartAppAd;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;



public class Esrarengiz extends Activity {

private StartAppAd startAppAd = new StartAppAd(this);

@Override
public void onResume(){
super.onResume();
startAppAd.onResume();
}




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_esrarengiz);
    StartAppSearch.showSearchBox(this);








    ImageButton ImageButton1=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    ImageButton1.getBackground().setAlpha(10);
    ImageButton cikisButton=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnCikis);
    cikisButton.getBackground().setAlpha(10);
    ImageButton btnHakkinda=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnHakkinda);
    btnHakkinda.getBackground().setAlpha(10);
    ImageButton btnTarikatlar=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnTarikat);
    btnTarikatlar.getBackground().setAlpha(10);
    ImageButton btnBasin=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnBasin);
    btnBasin.getBackground().setAlpha(10);

    ImageButton btnDoga=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnDoga);
    btnDoga.getBackground().setAlpha(10);

    ImageButton btnDestek=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnDestek);
    btnDestek.getBackground().setAlpha(10);

    ImageButton btnArsiv1=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnArsiv1);
    btnArsiv1.getBackground().setAlpha(10);

        btnDestek.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {






        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Uri link = Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/    details?id=com.martlost.esrarengizolaylar&feature=search_result");

        Intent tara = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DEFAULT, link);
        startActivity(tara);


        }
    });




    btnDoga.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {






        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent("com.martlost.esrarengizolaylar.DOGA1"));

        }
    });


    btnBasin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent("com.martlost.esrarengizolaylar.BASIN1"));

        }
    });


    btnTarikatlar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {







        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent("com.martlost.esrarengizolaylar.TARIKAT1"));

        }
    });


    btnHakkinda.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {






        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent("com.martlost.esrarengizolaylar.H"));

        }
    });




cikisButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
 });


    ImageButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            startActivity(new Intent   ("com.martlost.esrarengizolaylar.EKRANSIFIR"));



        }
    });


}

public void btnOpenActivity (View view){
    startAppAd.showAd();
    startAppAd.loadAd();
    Intent nextActivity = new Intent(this, basin1.class);
    startActivity(nextActivity);
    }

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
startAppAd.onBackPressed();
super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_esrarengiz, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

And

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/scroll"
 >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/hosgeldiniz" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="Dünya tarihine adını yazdırmış fakat sırrı hala çözülememiş bir çok hikaye ve gizemini koruyan bir çok olayı bu uygulamada görebilirsiniz."
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnDoga"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnTarikat"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/arsivuc" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnTarikat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnBasin"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:src="@drawable/arsiviki" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnHakkinda"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnDestek"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnDestek"
    android:src="@drawable/hakkinda" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnArsiv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnDestek"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnTarikat"
    android:src="@drawable/arsivdort" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginRight="21dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnDoga"
    android:background="@id/btnArsiv1"
    android:src="@drawable/arsivbir" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnBasin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnHakkinda"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/arsivdort" />






<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnDestek"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/destek" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnCikis"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/cikis" />

<com.startapp.android.publish.banner.Banner
    android:id="@+id/startAppBanner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
</com.startapp.android.publish.banner.Banner>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: there is a syntax error in the xml and it fails in line number 63. Which line is that?

Comment: <ImageButton
      its btnHakkinda Button

Comment: some part of the question is written in non-english.

Comment: Sorry this part same english part i translate to my country language because the system does not allow me to ask the question with less words

Comment: Post your entire stack trace.